# Two mixitup on one page under tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-tabs, mixitup

I am trying to connect the most popular filter plugin, MixItUp, with another popular tabs plugin.
The problem occurs when I add two different mixes under two tabs - the second one wont initiate. I followed all the examples for having two mixes, with no obviuos reason it fails.

It is a larger project which I will release as open-source, so if someone can spot something, would be much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/koteva/2o2hxnwu/1/

```
$(function(){
   $('#Container').mixItUp({
layout: {
        display: 'block'
    },    
selectors: {
   filter: '.filter_one'
 }
   });

 $('#Container_two').mixItUp({
layout: {
        display: 'block'
    },
    selectors: {
   filter: '.filter_two'
 }
});
});
```